# ExtJS. Checkbox in sourceConfig of property grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

In `sourceConfig` of property grid i have a field, which i want to be displayed as checkbox.

Currently, i'm set up only editor, but it renders checkbox only when field is clicked, else it shows simple text:

```
field: {
    editor:
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', { field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox')})
}
```

Question is, how can i set up renderer to show checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the [render](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.property.Grid.html#cfg-sourceConfig) function in the source config.

Something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    source: {
        "(name)": "My Object",
        Available: false,
        NotAvaliable: true,
        "Version": 0.01,
        "Description": "A test object"
    },
    sourceConfig: {
        Available: {
            renderer: function(d){
                var checked = d ? 'checked' : '';
                return '<center><input type="checkbox" name="something" '+checked+'></center>';
            },
            editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox')
        },
        NotAvaliable: {
            renderer: function(d){
                var checked = d ? 'checked' : '';
                return '<center><input type="checkbox" name="something" '+checked+'></center>';
            },
            editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox')
        }

    }

});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lsk

[image]